# Is there way to connect chrome devtools with sublime?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there way to highlighting or moving caret to appropriate line of code in sublime when i inspect html using chrome devtools inspector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this kind of functionality isn't possible. I have [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34528892/2604748) which explains why this kind of functionality is infeasible.