# Are you able to get hints from what template a message is coming from with dev tools?

Tags: templates, opencart, google-chrome-devtools

I have this website that I'm editing for a friend and they want to get rid of this message at the checkout screen but their boss doesnt know who implemented it. Its an error message at the top in read that says "If you are having trouble checking out, please contact us at sales@cbobaby.com" and is in the check out page. This is an [open cart website](https://www.cbobaby.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout) and I only work with wordpress sites so I'm having trouble figuring out where the source of the message is coming from. I've dug through some of the template files in the theme and I can't seem to find or delete anything that gets rid of it. My question is if there is anything in Chrome dev tools that would help me identify the source or template it lives in? I only use dev tools for adjusting css but I know there's so much more you can do it with. Thanks.

Comment: Does your IDE not have a good "Find in Files" function? If it's not dynamic text pulled from a DB that will find it real quick.

Comment: Would I still have that ability if I'm editing this via FTP? That sounds like something I would have to have a development environment?

Comment: I've just hid it with css until I can figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, you wouldn't really be able to do it over FTP - unless you did have ssh access and then you could search for that string so at least it would point out the file. No IDE, editing over FTP (and going to take a stab and say no VCS as well) on a Friday before Memorial Day? Ballsy, even for a small edit  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, DevTools can't relate your front-end code to what generates it for the DOM. For the exact same reason we are unable to [persist edits in the DOM to your source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523646/save-html-locally-from-devtools/34528892#34528892).

You need to use grep, or some code editor with "find all" functionality and look for some part of the string. If that fails, search your database and see if it is coming out of there. You can then either edit the database and hope nothing breaks, or try to back-track through the application logic to find where is calling that part of the DB. It should give you some ground as to where to look.

Answer (score 0):

In the Sources tab, you can see the resources, that are loaded when you are on a particular page. You can also use the Inspect tool in the Elements tab to find the element that hosts that bit of text to narrow things down in your search.

To add to this, if content is generated on the server side, the resources you see will likely be a merge from multiple generated sources, e.g. with templates in your case. You can search your solution for aspects of the DOM elements you see in Chrome Developer Tools, but look for the static parts instead of the dynamic parts. For example, the text itself won't be part of the template file, a placeholder will exist - a CSS class could be useful.

Comment: But that just shows you the resources the front end is looking for, it's not going to show the different templates that make up the page. It may certainly help OP narrow it down a bit, but that's about it.

Comment: Yeah I feel like I've done that and I feel so stupid for not being able to find it.

Comment: @patricksweeney Yes, if the content is generated server side, it's not going to be a straight forward file. But searching for some elements (without the content) within the solution/folder structure will help.